# Ошибка в php 7.1 при умножении sha1 хэша на время

Tags: php7, warning, sha1

Мой скрипт при переводе на php 7.1 начал выдавать

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Багует вот эта строка

```
 private function getRandString()
 {
     return substr(sha1(rand(0,1000000) * microtime()),0,32);
 }
```

Насколько я понял ошибка из-за того что я sha1 хэш умножаю на время.
Как это поправить правильно? не пойму.
надо и sha1 хэш и microtime привести к integer ?

Comment: Проблема в `microtime()` без аргументов. Поменяй на `microtime(true)`. Иначе она возвращает массив, а не время.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так это исправляется:

```
private function getRandString()
{
    return substr((int) sha1(rand(0, 1000000) * (int) microtime()), 0, 32);
}
```

И всё работает.